# Achieve a diagonal textview/layout effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I came across this diagonal effect in a game I was playing and wondered how I can achieve such an effect.

**Desired output**

[image]

I thought I could achieve the effect by simply adjusting the *rotation* but that didn't work, how can I achieve such a layout?

I can apply an image that looks similar but I want to animate the text as well

Comment: add this property for textview in xml `android:rotation="10"`

Comment: @ManoharReddy that does not produce the desired output as I had tried it before

Comment: Whats the output ? can you share screen shot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default pivot (both X and Y values) of a view is 0, so setting the rotation only will not work. Here's how to achieve your desired result:

**in XML** **(set the width to extend the screen width & apply the rotation)**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="Your text"
        android:rotation="10" />
```

**in JAVA (set the pivot point to the top left of the textview)**

```
    yourTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            yourTextView.setPivotX(0);
            yourTextView.setPivotY(0);

            yourTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```